# How to pass basic authentication in mysqldb python package?

Tags: python, mysql, authentication, basic-authentication

```
db = sql.connect(host,"username","password","dbname", basic_auth=('test', 'test'))
```

Comment: This yield as TypeError: 'basic_auth' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

How do I pass the base authentication sql.connect statement?enter code here

Comment: The term "basic authentication" isn't used for mysql db connections, it's something you might see when using a web frontend (e.g. phpmyadmin) to access a db, but that is irrelevant for a direct connection. What results (errors) do you get when you just leave out that `basic_auth` argument?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for mysql connector:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer but actually I need to pass basic authentication.

Comment: I am not familiar with basic auth for connection to db (are you sure about that?) but in this example seems like you need to import it (for requests):
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

In MySQLdb, you can use the connect() function to create a connection to the database. It has various parameters to it, which you can see in the link here: http://structure.usc.edu/mysqldb/MySQLdb-3.html.
There is no parameter called basic_auth (which you have used in your code) in the list of parameters.

MySQLdb uses the username and password that you specify to authenticate. Here is an example:

```
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user = 'root', passwd = 'test')
```